# What does the ${} Template variable accomplish?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, ide, code-generation

What does the ${} Template variable accomplish? It is used in the `sysout` template:

`System.out.println(${word_selection}${});${cursor}`

Comment: If you look closely, it actually appears in most templates in form of `${word_selection}${}`, not just in sysout. Take a look at "ToolItem" (SWT statements group), for example.

Comment: And that is exactly why I didn't make it an answer. However, it does look like `${}` does not mean anything by itself, since it does not appear "in wild" - only with conjunction with `${word_selection}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${}` is the empty placeholder, e.g. if the given template is executed:

```
System.out.println(${word_selection}${});${cursor}
```

the cursor will initially be positioned at the location of `${}` and you can type additional text. After you have finished typing, press Tab or Enter and you will be taken to `${cursor}`. Also you can have `${}` in several locations in the template; in this case the text you type will appear in every location where the `${}` is.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Eclipse documentation about [Template variables](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm), 
`${}` is just the empty placeholder (a place you are invited to input something after template instanciation).

Comment: It's not on that list though.

Comment: And where in that documentation is it explained what an empty template variable does? Your answer should contain more than just a link.